# How to display text from a query into a textbox

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, textbox, expressionbuilder

I have a textbox on my report and I have a query which always returns a single cell:

```
SELECT CustomMessage FROM OrderSheetSettings;
```

My aim is to display the single cell that it returns and place it into the textbox through the expression builder.

What I have/tried so far:

```
[qryCustomMessage]![CustomMessage]
[qryCustomMessage]![CustomMessage].Value
```

But this returns '#Name' or '#Error'

Any help on this would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=Dlookup("CustomMessage","OrderSheetSettings")
```

Comment: It was that simple... Thanks a lot!